# NBA Street v3: how to play career mode only with created ballers?

Tags: ps2, nba-street-v3

I used to play NBA Street v3 (PS2) a lot back a few years. Today I decided to start all over again. I remember playing career mode only with created ballers using my custom team (if I'm not crazy!) but now I can't find a way to do that.

Every time I try to start a career, I can only choose one created baller which becomes the team captain. I've created a custom team which contains only ballers created by me, but when I try to start a career, I can only choose one.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible at all?

I'm just wondering what's the point of creating a custom team if I can't play with it.

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Giovanna